# How to catch an exception in for loop but at the end throw one?

Tags: python, for-loop, exception

I want to catch an Exception in a for loop, and print a message in all items of the for loop, but at the end, still throw an Exception, so that I know the script failed. How to do that?

I'm trying this for now:

```
for key, value in marketplaces.items():
    try:
        r = requests.post(value, data=json.dumps({'Content': message(key, res)}), verify=False)
    except:
        r = requests.post(value, data=json.dumps({'Content': "Sorry, an error occured"}), verify=False)
```

But with this code, I only catch the exception and post an error message to all items in the for loop, but don't know that the script failed. I want to know this and throw and exception, **after** posting an error message to **all** items in for loop.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Well, catch it, store it, raise it later…? `except Exception as e: err = e` … `if err: raise err`

Comment: Sorry, didn't got it really... How do you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to set a variable inside the `except` clause and check it after the loop is done. The example below is roughly what you need.

Note that there could be more than one failure, so we use a list to store *all* the errors, and report them all at the end.

**Also note that the correct way to catch an exception in Python is to catch a *specific* exception -- in this case, it suffices to catch the `requests.exceptions` base class.**

The code below stores the exception string `e` in the list of errors and afterwards, we check if there are *any* errors, and raise a new exception with the entire list of errors.

In this case, we're just raising the most generic exception type for `requests` exceptions -- `requests.exceptions.RequestException` (i.e. the base class once again). This is because there are various possible errors which could have occurred during the requests. Depending on your use case, you might prefer another more standard exception type, such as `RuntimeError` -- see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) for the standard exception types.

```
import requests

errors = []

for key, value in marketplaces.items():
    try:
        r = requests.post(value, data=json.dumps({'Content': message(key, res)}), verify=False)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        r = requests.post(value, data=json.dumps({'Content': "Sorry, an error occured"}), verify=False)
        errors.append(str(e))

if errors:
    raise requests.exceptions.RequestException(errors)
```

**Alternative:**

Though the above is a fairly common approach that suits many use cases, it may be convoluted in some situations. Hence, I'm proposing a much simpler and more trivial alternative, which may also suit your needs, or anyone else who stumbles across this. Simply print out an error message each time an exception is raised (i.e. each time the code enters the `except` clause), like this:

```
import requests
import sys

for key, value in marketplaces.items():
    try:
        r = requests.post(value, data=json.dumps({'Content': message(key, res)}), verify=False)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        r = requests.post(value, data=json.dumps({'Content': "Sorry, an error occured"}), verify=False)
        print(str(e), file=sys.stderr)
```

*Hope this helps!*